# What is the Japanese meaning of the name "Kakka"?

Tags: translation, names, culture

In *Man In The High Castle* (S2E04 I believe) a character is referred to in Japanese as "Kakka".

Is this a common name?

And, does this name have a specific meaning? If so, what?

Comment: you are not alone spanish person, kakka is also poo in finnish. there is an old popular anime called " Legend of Galactic Heroes ", which used the word extensively through the very long series.

Comment: Interestingly also какa in Russian translates to "like" in English.

Comment: This is very interesting. In my language Kannada "kakka" is a slang for "shit" used by some people. It is not common nor is it part of the formal language. I do not know if it is an import from some foreign language. However there is another word `kaka` (notice the single k). That is used by a large number of Kannada and Marathi speaking people to refer to one's father's brother.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Kakka" is far from popular; it's virtually nonexistent as a Japanese person name.

But there is a word [閣下](http://jisho.org/search/%E9%96%A3%E4%B8%8B) ("kakka"), which is a word used to address heads of government/state. It's like English "Your Excellency" or "Your Highness".

The kanji character 閣 ("kak(u)") means "(government) cabinet/building/palace," and 下 ("ka") means "below/under." Put together, 閣下 is used to indirectly refer to someone under the Cabinet (building's ceiling). Of course it's not related to any Spanish nouns, and very few people care how it sounds to Spanish people.

Comment: [デーモン小暮閣下](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A2%E3%83%B3%E9%96%A3%E4%B8%8B)（笑）

Comment: There is a restaurant in Toronto called "KAKA all you can eat", so I certainly hoped KAKA didn't have the Spanish meaning in Japanese. Still, I haven't tried the restaurant.